# Help to understand the validness of relation in a model

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, satisfiability

In my assignment I have the following question:
Find a model $M$ with domain $\{a, b, c, d\}$ so that:

> $M\vDash R(\overline{a},\overline{b})\land R(\overline{b},\overline{a})\land\neg Q(\overline{d})$
>
> $M\vDash\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x)),$
>
> $M\vDash\forall x(R(x,x)\to P(x))$,
>
> $M\vDash\forall x\exists y (R(x,y))$

where $R^M$ is a transitive relation.

What I struggle to understand here is how the negation of $Q$ can be true with the input $\overline{d}$, however later it is expected that for all $x$, if $P(x)$ is true, it implies that $Q(x)$ too shall be true (according to the truth table for implication).

How I interpret this is that $x$ can be everything in the domain, so either $a, b, c\text{ or }d$, but since the NEGATION of $Q$ with  $\overline{d}$ as input is true, isn't there a contradiction here?

How is the negation (of this relation $Q$) meant to be understood here?

Comment: What is the bar over $d$ stand for ?

Comment: @Manx it is not entirely explained, but as from our textbooks we are meant to interpret it as the constant variable version of {d} as per the domain. So as to differ the constant variables of a signature as opposed to the direct values from the domain. I suppose it might be why I misinterpret this question, but I don't see entirely why this would have a significance besides showing which exact variable we are talking about, in this case d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction. The idea is that $P$ must be false for $d$.

Consider the following interpretation in the domain $\{a,b,c,d\}$:
\begin{align}
R^M &= \{(a,b), (b,a), (a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,c)\} \\
P^M &= \{a,b,c\} \\
Q^M &= \{a,b,c\} \\
\end{align}
It is immediate to prove that $R^M$ is transitive and that the structure $M$ (where each $x \in \{a,b,c,d\}$ is the interpretation of the constant $\overline{x}$) satisfies the four axioms.

Comment: would any, complete type of transitive relation on R^M still count as correct, or are there any specifics to this relation that works only for this? Edit: Pardon me! I forgot the first rule of "a,b - b,a". Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I thought I had one more question but I think I understood it. Is it true that, on rule (1), that the constant variable of d- is still represented in R^M, because the rule states only the negation of Q? Would I need to make the transitive relation of R^M without d if it stated, e.g: -R(d-, d-) ? Hope the poor formatting is understandable. Edit: I suppose my point is better explained if there was 2 new rules: -R(d-, x) and -R(x, d-)

Comment: @lowkeybuddhist - I'm not sure to understand your question (and please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/288417) for a readable formatting). Anyway, the structure $M$ interprets each constant $\overline{x}$ with $x$, for every $x \in \{a,b,c,d\}$. The fact that $d \notin Q^M$ means that $M \not\models Q(\overline{d})$, i.e., $M \models \lnot Q(\overline{d})$.

Comment: @lowkeybuddhist - Moreover, $R^M$ is transitive, even with respect to $d$, because in the structure $M$ I provided the only possibility to make $R(x,y)$ and $R(y,z)$ true with $x = d$ or $y = d$ or $z = d$ is when $x = d$ and $y = c = z$, and in this case $M$ makes $R(x,z)$ true because $(c,c) \in R^M$.

Comment: My question is if it would theoretically be possible for a rule (5) to take the negation of R, and make it valid with "d" as argument passed. Thus, the negation of the negation, meaning R, would be invalid if it had "d" as argument. You don't have to answer, it's just for my own curiousity! Marked question as answered :)

Comment: @lowkeybuddhist - Note that the structure $M$ I provided satisfies also $M \models \lnot  R(\overline{d}, \overline{d})$ (among many other consequences). But if you require also $M \models R(\overline{d}, \overline{d})$ as a fifth axiom, you get a contradiction (i.e. there would be no models for the five axioms such that $R^M$ is transitive) because $(d,d) \in R^M$ implies $d \in P^M$ (by the third axiom) which implies $d \in Q^M$ (by the second axiom), which contradicts the first axiom.